# Acting as a server outside LAN

Tags: c++, c, tcp, ip, lan

I'm currently writing a peer-to-peer chat application to chat around the world, but my problem is that I can't connect() to another computer outside my LAN because although I have the public IP address of my friends and if necessary I could get their private IP address, how can I connect to their PC since the public IP address is the router's address, not the computer's one and I can only specify one address (either the public or the private). So how can I send the message to the computer in specific and not to the router without having to setup it?. I know it's possible because otherwise if you requested a web page all the computers in your lan can get your private information (in a wired scheme, since in wi-fi it's clearly possible).
Any help would be appreciated, sorry for my poor English :D.

Comment: What exactly is the specific question? The simplest chat system I could think of would use HTML posts or messages through a web service to clients running in a browser. If you are making a fat client and want to chat with other clients you could use tcp/ip sockets.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that possibility, since I am getting my friend list from get's to a PHP on my server, but I wish I could chat with them in a P2P style, totally anonymously except from the login's, and the logout's.

Comment: You could use a P2P protocol like Bittorrent easily enough assuming the it's available on the other machines. I can't think of any machine that doesn't have tcp/ip or a browser though.

Comment: thank you, I'll read some documentation about Bittorrent and see what I can get

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and reassess - before you start trying to talk to arbitrary PCs, try writing a chat application that works on your own network (and I mean app-app not app-windows messenger service) This will give you a far better understanding of the principles involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1 Read around here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

2 Go for IPv6! ;-)

Comment: does IPv6 have a "one IP per PC" shceme?

Comment: if so, I could go and delete all my TCP/IP code right here, right now :D

Comment: @chubakueno: At least the number of possible IPv6 addresses is large enough to not have to do any NAT anymore. There are so many you could assign an offical IP even to your coffee machine.

Comment: :lol, so with IPv6 every PC have a unique public IP altough they are behind a router?

Comment: The router isn't the issue. The NAT done by (DSL-)routers in current IPv4 networking is the issue.

Comment: Thank you @alk, I'll go modify my code and test it with IPv6.I'll also do some ping's on my local machines.

Comment: Cheers! Give it a try ... - but branch your code and keep your IPv4 version, you might want to come back to it (see option 1 above, punching holes could be fun) ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the private IP address of computers on the other side of the router will not help you. In these situations, if they initiate the connection to you, then you are fine as you can respond on that connection.

If you want to initiate the connection to them, you *must* to it to their public IP address and they must have their router configured to map the inbound request (on whatever port) to the correct IP address in their network.

Comment: So I can't start a connection with another computer if both are behind a router?.

Comment: It does not matter where the initiating computer is (assuming the router/firewall will let the connection out), but the target computer, if behind a router, needs to have the router configured properly. There is no way to "reach into the router" to get to a computer.

Comment: Unsolicited connection requests will be summarily rejected by any machine with even a token bit of security. Your chat application needs to be running on the machines involved and then they can listen for connections both ways.

Comment: @chubakueno: Haha do these "friends" know that you'd like to "chat" with them?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be sure that the computer you are trying to connect is listening to a specific port (the same one that you are trying to connect to).

You will also need to configure your friends routers so that they forward all the request on that port to your friends' computers. If you don't have access to the routers, it is probably best to use a computer that is not behind any router as the chat server.

Comment: yes, the problem is that I want a totally anonymous chat except for login's and logout's (where you connect with the database and download your personal info). But if I can't do it P2P, is fine.

Comment: That's a conflicting statement ;-) Requiring logins and a database of personal info is the exact opposite of anonymous.

Comment: more precisely, I want that my server never knows what someone and her gf are talking :D

Comment: What do you mean by "my server never knows"? The only function of the server would be to listen to connections, and forward packets between two computers. As long as you don't save those packets or analyze them, the server should never know. You can also implement end-to-end encryption if you need more security.

Comment: it's a possibility, so if I couldn't do it with IPv6 as @alk said, I'll do it with a PHP intermediary.

Comment: I don't see how IPv6 will solve your problem. The problem is that the other person is behind a router using NAT. If you can convince the other person to change to IPv6, it would be much easier to convince them to change their routers to do port forwarding.

Comment: if the other person isn't using IPv6, I'll let him know he has to download the non-P2P version, and everyone is happy ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to use [uPNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play). This allows your application to talk to the router(s) on the current network and ask them to forward the appropriate messages to you. This then makes a hole in the firewall which allows your app (on another PC) to connect.

Assuming both apps do this, either end can initiate the connection. If only one end has the app, then the OTHER end must initiate connection.

Imagine [what would happen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messenger_Service#Abuse) if everyone on the internet could just send messages to anyone - with no software pre-installed...